# Fatal error: Index out of range with firebase multiple arrays

Tags: swift

I made an app with multiple collectionViews and the collectionViews recive data (images) from firebase everything is working fine the images appear in every section. until I select (to show details) the images at the very end of any collection except for one collection which has the least number of images

1. collection no. 1 has 10 images ===> I can select the images from 1
   to 7
2. collection no. 2 has 13 images ===> I can select the images from 1
   to 7
3. collection no. 3 has 7 images ===> I can select all the images

if I select any image higher than no 7 the app crash and I got the error "Fatal error: Index out of range"

my codes:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
       if collectionView == collectionView1 {
        
        return foodCollection1.count
        }
        if collectionView == collectionView2 {
        return foodCollection2.count
        }
        if collectionView == collectionView3 {
        return foodCollection3.count
        }
      
     else {
      return headerCollection.count
    }
   
}
```

and I go the error at let food4  =  foodCollection4[indexPath.row]

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let food1  =  foodCollection1[indexPath.row]
        let food2  =  foodCollection2[indexPath.row]
        let food3  =  foodCollection3[indexPath.row]
        let food4  =  foodCollection4[indexPath.row]
        
        if collectionView == collectionView1 {
        let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsViewController") { (coder) in
            return DetailsViewController(coder: coder, item3: food1 )
        }
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC!, animated: true)
        }
            if collectionView == collectionView2 {

        let detailVC2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsViewController") { (coder) in
            return DetailsViewController(coder: coder, item3: food2 )
        }
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC2!, animated: true)

        }
                if collectionView == collectionView3 {

        let detailVC3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsViewController") { (coder) in
            return DetailsViewController(coder: coder, item3: food3 )
        }
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC3!, animated: true)
       
    
}
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Don't do `let food1`, `let food2` etc. in `didSelectIteamAt`. Imagine the first array have only 1 item, and the second one has 7. What happens then if the indexPath.row is 6 ? You'll get that error. So, don't do it like that, instead, according to which collectionView it is (you `if collectionView ==`, get `food1`, or `food2`, etc.

Comment: You need a complete redo of the `didSelectItemAt` method. The entire thing goes down if any one of the arrays has a different number of elements in it. You need to extract the element according to the need.

Comment: @Frankenstein I'm a beginner and this is the only way i know of. What is the other ways?

Comment: @Larme Thank you could you please clear up the last line in your answer

Comment: Create `let food2  =  foodCollection2[indexPath.row]` only when needed. Here, it's in the case/scope you wrote `if collectionView == collectionView2 {`, else it's useless (and doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Larme but i need to write food2 = foodCollection2[indexPath.row] and the rest of them for the coder part (coder: coder, item3: food2 )

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

With the help I figured it out. All i had to do is this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if collectionView == collectionView1 {

        let food1  =  foodCollection1[indexPath.row]

        let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailsViewController") { (coder) in
            return DetailsViewController(coder: coder, item3: food1 )
        }
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC!, animated: true)
        }

..... etc
```